# The index value still get 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ticker

Why the 'index' always return value 0 although the ticker running and there is a statement 'index = index + 1'?

```
'Dim index as integer = 0
'EDIT
Dim GridRowIndex as integer

Protected Sub TickerAnnouncement_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  TickerAnnouncement.Tick
    lblAnnouncementFooter.Text = GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text
    'index = index + 1

    If GridRowIndex> GridView1.Rows.Count Then GridRowIndex = 0
End Sub
```

I have turned the tick enabled but the index still returning the 0 value.

---ADDITION---

I have a property called 'IndexValue':

```
Public Property IndexValue() As Integer
    Get
        Dim s As Integer = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowIndex"), Integer)
        Return If(ViewState("GridRowIndex") Is Nothing, 0, CInt(ViewState("GridRowIndex")) + 1)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        ViewState("GridRowIndex") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the statement is actually executed? How did you make sure? Did you by any chance declare a local variable called `index`? Right-click on the local `index` variable and choose “Go to definition”. Where does it jump?

Comment: What is this, Winforms, ASP.NET, WPF ,...? If it's ASP.NET it's obvious why it's always 0. All variables, controls(including the page itself) will be disposed as soon as the page is rendered to the client(HTTP is stateless).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: All the statement executed but there was only returned the value of rows(0) from GridView1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: this is ASP .Net. So what should I do in order to make the index value does not returning the same value?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 Well there are only three possibilities: (1) The increment statement wasn’t executed, (2) `index` inside the method refers to another variable, or (3) the value is actually incremented. That’s it; it has to be either of those.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: Use the ViewState as i've showed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Timer.Tick` will cause a postback. All objects that belongs to the page(member variables,controls etc.) are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. So when it's rendered to the client, it doesn't exist in the Server's memory anymore. [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is **stateless**.  Hence every variable(or dynamically created control) must be reinitialized/recreated on postbacks. This is the reason why your `index` is always 0.

So you need to store it elsewhere. I would recommend the [`ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S9):

```
ViewState["GridRowIndex"] = ViewState["GridRowIndex"] == null ? 0 : (int)ViewState["GridRowIndex"]+1;
```

**Edit**:

I've just realized that this is a VB.NET question,sorry.

Declare this property:

```
Public Property IndexValue() As Integer
    Get
        If ViewState("GridRowIndex") Is Nothing Then ViewState("GridRowIndex") = 0
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowIndex"), Int32)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        ViewState("GridRowIndex") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then set it in your event-handler:

```
Protected Sub TickerAnnouncement_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  TickerAnnouncement.Tick
    lblAnnouncementFooter.Text = GridView1.Rows(IndexValue).Cells(0).Text
    IndexValue += 1
    If IndexValue >= GridView1.Rows.Count Then IndexValue = 0
End Sub
```

You will find a complete list of all options on how to persist variables across postbacks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

- Application
- Cookies
- Form Post / Hidden Form Field
- QueryString
- Session
- New State Containers in ASP.NET
- Cache
- Context
- **ViewState**
- Web.config and Machine.config Files

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I still get stuck. Please see the code above (I have edited), did I place the code on the right place? I am not quite familiar on using ViewState

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: I've just realized that you need VB.NET, see my edit.

Comment: It's work, thanks. But after reach the gridview maximum rows, the index value doesn't return to the 0 value. So it's stuck on the maximum rows, e.g. The total rows on gridview is 3, after I've executed the code, it will get 1, 2, 3 and then stuck (I want that it always re-occured, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: Of course(edited my answer). `GridView1.Rows.Count` does return the count of rows starting with 1 and `IndexValue` is the index of the rows beginning with 0. So to get the first row you would call `GridView1.Rows(0)`. So i've changed `>` to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the count of the rows in your GridView?

This line will always set your index integer back to 0 if you have no rows in the grid.

```
 If index > GridView1.Rows.Count Then index = 0
```

Also breakpoint the method and see what happens, step through the code and check the value of all the variables etc.

Comment: There are some rows in the grid.

The purpose of this code is to make a news-ticker that the data is taken from the gridview